# how to configure main class path in tanuki wrapper for spring boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, classpath, wrapper, java-service-wrapper

I am using a spring boot application and after build my project using maven, i can see a jar file of my application with maintaining following folder structure

[image]

```
buddika@buddika-pc:~/Desktop/visitor-tracking-automation-api-server/bin$ ll /home/buddika/Desktop/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  6 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 33 buddika buddika 12288 Sep 18 23:14 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:08 BOOT-INF/
drwxr-xr-x  3 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:08 META-INF/
drwxr-xr-x  3 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:08 org/
```

but problem is in tanuki wrapper. it is not identify this (BOOT-INF/classes/com/visitor/tracking/automation/api/boot/APIServerStart) folder structure.

[image]

instead above folder structure of jar, it is expecting following folder structure. I manually brought "com" folder to the front from BOOT-INF. that time wrapper is identify the main class and worked

[image]

```
buddika@buddika-pc:~/Desktop/visitor-tracking-automation-api-server/bin$ ll /home/buddika/Desktop/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  6 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 33 buddika buddika 12288 Sep 18 23:14 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:08 BOOT-INF/
drwxr-xr-x  3 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:08 com/
drwxr-xr-x  3 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:08 META-INF/
drwxr-xr-x  3 buddika buddika  4096 Sep 18 22:08 org/
```

my question is how to configure this main class path without manually bring the "com" package to front.

is there a way to make the jar by bring "com" package to front without putting in to "BOOT-INF"

following configurations were used in wrapper.conf file

```
wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.working.dir=..
wrapper.java.mainclass=com.visitor.tracking.automation.api.boot.APIServerStarter
set.default.REPO_DIR=lib
set.default.APP_BASE=.
```

Comment: Text is prefered over images etc.

Comment: Why do you need Tanuki to start an Spring Boot App ?

Comment: could you pls suggest me a ultra native solution then @khmarbaise

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service check this, here also suggesting the thanuki wrapper

Comment: This question is similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50695561/wrapping-spring-boot-application-with-tanuki-service-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting the Main class to `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` instead of my application's Main class.

The [documentation for `JarLauncher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.html) says:

> Launcher for JAR based archives. This launcher assumes that dependency jars are included inside a /BOOT-INF/lib directory and that application classes are included inside a /BOOT-INF/classes directory.

This way, you don't have to move your package to the root of the jar—the "org" folder shown in your screenshots should already have the path to `JarLauncher`.